# Best way to record a prospects product interest through a hidden field when they submit a Pardot form

Tags: forms, salesforce, pardot

I would like to know the best method when it comes to recording a prospects product interest when they submit a pardot form. I do not want this to be visible to the user and I want to be sure this field won’t overwrite itself if the same prospect submits a separate form with a different interest value. Any tips on the best way to do this? (A detailed response is most appreciated, thanks!)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question needs improvement. Please read: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Can you show us what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the option "Record and display multiple responses" you can apply to a Prospect field. This will allow you to collect multiple responses over time. I am not a huge fan of this because a prior response could have been years ago, and it's potentially confusing to have a really old interest commingled with the current interest.

Another option is to have the above setting on a 'cumulative interest' PLUS a seperate 'most recent interest' field. This gives you a more nuanced data collection plus having all the history.

Hidden form fields populated with the values work well to collect and populate the values.